# Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation in mlr3

Tags: cross-validation, mlr3

I like to use Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation in mlr3 (as part of a pipeline).

I could specify the number of folds (=number of instances) e.g. via

```
resampling = rsmp("cv", folds=task$nrow)
```

But this refers explicitly to "task" which may not work in the pipeline.

How can I proceed here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a specific ["leave-one-out" `Resampling` object](https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_resamplings_loo.html), named `"loo"`. It can be used like any `Resampling` object, for example:

```r
rs <- rsmp("loo")
rr <- resample(tsk("iris"), lrn("classif.rpart"), resampling = rs)
rr$aggregate()
#> classif.ce
#> 0.06666667
```

It determines the number of iterations directly from the `Task` being used, and has no configuration parameters (i.e. has an empty `$param_set`).